# Avoid duplicated services in dependecy injection

Tags: web-services, symfony, dependency-injection, console

I need your advices to avoid duplicating services in a Symfony Dependecy Injection project.

The project goal is to create Symfony Console commands to manage objects of a remote Service. The Service exposes API to manage the objects.

The remote Service gives me two different instance to work with: the production instance and the sandbox instance.

Examples of commands to execute are:

- create user on instance X
- create group on instance X
- show difference between users of the two instances
- sync users between the two instances

I started creating a Class to wrap the Service API and creating two services using the same class with different authentication data for the two instances:

```
services:

    sandbox_instance:
        class: APIClient
        arguments: ["sandbox_account", "sandbox_user", "sandbox_password"]

    prod_instance:
        class: APIClient
        arguments: ["prod_account", "prod_user", "prod_password"]
```

But then, I created some "managers" to have the logic of the different operations.
So for example, I created a UserManager and a GroupManager.
These services depends on the "ApiClient" services, so I ended up duplicating all the managers, one for the production, one for the sandbox:

```
services:

  ....

  user_manager_sandbox:
      class: UserManager
      arguments: ['@sandbox_instance']

  user_manager_prod:
      class: UserManager
      arguments: ['@prod_instance']


  group_manager_sandbox:
      class: GroupManager
      arguments: ['@sandbox_instance']

  group_manager_prod:
      class: GroupManager
      arguments: ['@prod_instance']
```

I'm sure this is not the correct way to use the service container, but I can't figure out how to define and get "parametric" services.

My goal, in the Command code would be to call:

```
$prodUserManager = $container->get('user_manager', 'prod');
$sandboxUserManager = $container->get('user_manager', 'sandbox');
```

and avoid duplicating the definition of the service.

Of course I cannot simply put authentication data in config parameters and load different configurations according to the instance I want to work with because there are some commands where I need to work with both instances (migration and diff commands, for example).

How can I do this in the correct way? What is the best practice?

Thank you very much in advance.
Cheers
Matteo

Comment: I suppose you could use a factory.  $prodUserManager = $container->get('user_manager_factory')->get('prod');  Gonna be messy no matter what.  Based on what you posted, I would just live with the duplicated services.

Comment: I'd like to answer you, if you're still interested and if you've tried Factory approach.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a service to switch the environment and using Expression Language in service definition:

Environment Switch class:

```
<?php

class EnvSwitch
{

  private $currentEnv;

  public function getCurrentEnv(){
    if($this->currentEnv == null)
      throw new \Exception('No environment selected yet.');
    return $this->currentEnv;
  }

  public function setCurrentEnv(string $env){
    $this->currentEnv = $env;
  }

  public function getCurrentEnvServiceName(){
    return $this->getCurrentEnv().'_instance';
  }

}
```

The services definition:

```
services:

    sandbox_instance:
        class: APIClient
        arguments: ["sandbox_account", "sandbox_user", "sandbox_password"]

    prod_instance:
        class: APIClient
        arguments: ["prod_account", "prod_user", "prod_password"]

     env_switch:
         class: EnvSwitch

     user_manager:
         class: UserManager
         arguments: ["@=service(service('env_switch').getCurrentEnvServiceName())"]
         shared: false

     group_manager:
         class: GroupManager
         arguments: ["@=service(service('env_switch').getCurrentEnvServiceName())"]
         shared: false
```

Usage in Console Command:

```
...
$this->get('env_switch')->setCurrentEnv('sandbox');
$userManager = $this->get('user_manager');
...
```

What do you think about this solution?
Matteo